# MongoDB shell getCollectionNames not working properly

Tags: mongodb-query

When in mongo shell 3.x I found this strange behaviour:

- Typing db.getCollectionNames() i get [] but I know that there are collections
- Typing db.myColl.findOne() in fact it returns  a document as I expect

Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: Pardon the silly qn. but are these executed under same database?

Comment: You're already on 3.x. so this shouldn't have any impact i take https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/

Comment: Thanks KaSh,your link was helpful. Effectively the problem is that I made un upgrade of deployment version from 2.6 to 3.x but the shell version is still 2.6.

Comment: Super! glad it helped. i guess upgrading the shell should do the trick.

Comment: Would you mind accepting it as answer?

Comment: Can't accept because your answer is in a comment...

Comment: right. i added it to answer now. Could you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already on 3.x. so this shouldn't have any impact i take ?

docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames
as the link says it returns empty array for shell lower than 3.X

Answer (score 1):

> For MongoDB 3.0 deployments using the WiredTiger storage engine, if
>   you run db.getCollectionNames() from a version of the mongo shell
>   before 3.0 or a version of the driver prior to 3.0 compatible version,
>   db.getCollectionNames() will return no data, even if there are
>   existing collections.

FOr more details, refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#considerations)